# How to Use CSS for Powershell Output (Semi Advanced)

Tags: javascript, html, css, powershell

So, I've been playing around with the powershell "Convertto-HTML" as well as the ConvertTo-EnhancedHTML (downloadable module) functions.  I've found a great looking table template online that uses CSS and Angular.  The CSS and Angular are above my paygrade and I'm hoping someone could help me format the output.
Using 
`Get-IAMUserList | Select Username, PasswordLastUsed, UserID |ConvertTo-Html -PreContent "<h2>User List</h2>"|Out-File report.htm`

It produces the following simple HTML (didn't include the header)

```html
<body>
<h2>User List</h2>
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>UserName</th><th>PasswordLastUsed</th><th>UserId</th></tr>
<tr><td>Joe</td><td>1/3/2020 4:36:24 PM</td><td>IPNB63</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sally</td><td>1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM</td><td>GRUIF</td></tr>
<tr><td>Joe</td><td>1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM</td><td>JI4H</td></tr>
<tr><td>user</td><td>1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM</td><td>Z4PM2</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Id like to use the code in this website to format this data (as an example).  I'd really like to use it as a template.  Can anyone help?  Here is the link --[Link to Code](https://codepen.io/chrisoncode/pen/AmFLE)

To be clear - I've looked up TONS of CSS examples for powershell output and have tried many of them.  Most all of them are pretty simple and I can get my data formatted.  But I really like the look of the more advanced stuff referenced in the link but can't figure it out b/c I don't understand CSS/JS very well.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks Theo!  I've looked up lots of  "simple" CSS examples and have been able to figure that out.  But what i want it to use the specific CSS/JS referenced in my post (or very similar).  But I don't understand CSS/JS enough to do it.

Comment: Guys, to be clear - I've looked up TONS of CSS examples for powershell output and have tried many of them.  Most all of them are pretty simple and I can get my data formatted.  But I really like the look of the more advanced stuff referenced in the link but can't figure it out b/c I don't understand CSS/JS very well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it "out of the box" using `ConvertTo-Html` and you want formatting, then you have to manually create some CSS to manually format. If you want to use the CSS that you like (you don't need Javascript if it is a static table), then one easy way is to build the table yourself.

I do it this way:

```
$UserList = Get-IAMUserList | Select Username, PasswordLastUsed, UserID

$HTMLHead = @'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.2.0/sandstone/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h2>User List</h2>

  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">  
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="#">UserName</a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">PasswordLastUsed</a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">UserId</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
'@

$HTMLRow = @'
      <tr>
        <td>{{UserName}}</td>
        <td>{{PasswordLastUsed}}</td>
        <td>{{UserId}}</td>
      </tr>
'@

$HTMLFoot = @'
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
'@

$HTMLTable = ''

$UserList | ForEach-Object {
    $Row = $HTMLRow.Replace('{{UserName}}', $_.UserName)
    $Row = $Row.Replace('{{PasswordLastUsed}}', $_.PasswordLastUsed)
    $Row = $Row.Replace('{{UserId}}', $_.UserId)

    $HTMLTable += $Row
}

#Assemble everything
$HTMLOut = $HTMLHead + $HTMLTable + $HTMLFoot

$HTMLOut |Out-File report.htm
```

Comment: This looks great!

Comment: you were superhelpful on this.  I was hoping you could guide me on a slightly different issue.  What about creating HTML output for a similar command but  needing to use a foreach loop. -- here is the catch.  The HTML report needs data both in the output of the for each loop command but also in the variable that was used in the for each loop.    For example $Group would be the input in a foreach statement like $users=(get-users -Group $Group) , The HTML output would need the name of the Group from the $group variable and the list of users from the $users variable.